# Django Create Account ends in 550

Tags: django, pinax

on a Django application ([geonode 2.4](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/tree/2.4.x)) I´m trying to register a new user: `me@gmail.com`. This ends in `ERROR SMTPRecipientsRefused sombody@yahoo.com (550, unknown User)`.

The same Setup works on a local vm (with same SMTP server)!

SETUP

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Django 1.6.11
- Accounts App: [geonode-user-accounts](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-user-accounts)
  (Forked from pinax-django-user-accounts)

SMTP local_settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@mail.example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pass'
EMAIL_PORT = 25 ## tested telnet to 587 but it seems only 25 is open
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
THEME_ACCOUNT_CONTACT_EMAIL = 'admin@example.com'
```

QUESTION

**What I do not understand why does Django complain about sombody@yahoo.com when I try to register me@gmail.com? – It should not care about already registered users. How can I debug this?**

TRACEBACK

```
   SMTPRecipientsRefused at /account/signup/
    {u'sombody@yahoo.com': (550, 'Unknown user')}
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://geonode.barbatti.org/account/signup/
    Django Version: 1.6.11
    Exception Type: SMTPRecipientsRefused
    Exception Value:    
    {u'max.muster@barbatti.de': (550, 'Unknown user')}
    Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py in sendmail, line 747
    Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
    Python Version: 2.7.6
    Python Path:    
    ['/var/www/geonode',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
     '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
     '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
     '/var/www']
    Server time:    Tue, 16 May 2017 09:52:13 -0500
    Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in view
                return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in dispatch
            return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/account/views.py in post
            return super(SignupView, self).post(*args, **kwargs) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py in post
                return self.form_valid(form) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/account/views.py in form_valid
                notification.send(staff, "account_approve", {"from_user": self.created_user}) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notification/models.py in send
                return send_now(*args, **kwargs) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notification/models.py in send_now
                    backend.deliver(user, sender, notice_type, extra_context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notification/backends/email.py in deliver
            send_mail(subject, body, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [recipient.email]) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py in send_mail
                            connection=connection).send() ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/message.py in send
            return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self]) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py in send_messages
                    sent = self._send(message) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py in _send
                self.connection.sendmail(from_email, recipients, message.as_bytes()) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py in sendmail
                raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs) ...
```

Comment: It's not Django complaining about `sombody@yahoo.com`, it's the mailserver. You shouldn't share your password here, but changing all the domains to `example.com` in your question could be hiding the problem.

Comment: Hi Alasdair, thanks a lot for your reply. What I do not get is why somebody@yahoo.com is involved here when me@example.com should be registered? Itt seems Django pulls out somebody@ from postgresql and passes it to the smtp server ... why?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, copy and paste the traceback instead. Since the error is occurring on `notificate.send(staff, ...)`, it looks as if it could be trying to send an email to a staff member with a yahoo address.

Comment: I´ve removed the snapshot and added the traceback. As this is for a client I cannot show the mail server or an E-Mail adress. I will work though the code and see if I can find where the data is pulled out of the DB and why the yahoo adress is involved here .

Comment: If you click the `Switch to copy-and-paste view` before copying and pasting then the traceback is easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, what happens here is that

```
ACCOUNT_APPROVAL_REQUIRED = True
```

is set. The mentioned yahoo adress is an admin, which should be informed for approval. The Smtp is refusing the adress and throwing the 550.